# Multi-Format File Viewer for .Net Development

Tags: .net, components

Is anyone aware of a multi-format file viewer, capable of displaying common image formats, as well as MS Office document formats (at least Word and Excel), and PDFs?  I've seen several image viewers available, but none besides Outside In from Oracle.

I'm looking for viewer technology that can be imbedded in a .net application - a mixture of vb and c#

Answer (score 1):

We embed an Internet Explorer ActiveX control into our application for doing this.  IE opens all of the files you listed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for asp.net then you can try Doconut,if needed it can also be embedded in a web browser control for winforms applications. It does not need any activeX, it is pure HTML / javascript control, native .net.